# How to save dynamic select list value into config table in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

I wanted to show list of fields per content type in admin config form. After saving the form, selected list value should get save into **config** table.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  foreach (node_type_get_types() as $content_type) {
    $entity_type_id = 'node';
    $fields = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', $content_type->get('type'));
    if ($fields) {
      $options = array();
      foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_definition) {
        if (!empty($field_definition->getTargetBundle())) {
          $options[$field_name] = $field_definition->getLabel();
        }
      }
      $form['test']['test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $content_type->get('name'),
        '#options' => array_merge(array('0' => t('Auto')), $options),
        '#default_value' => $config->get('test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field') ? $config->get('test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field') : '',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is submit handler

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

foreach (node_type_get_types() as $content_type) {
  $this->config('test.settings')
  ->set('test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field', $form_state->getValue('test', 'test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field'))
  ->save();
}     
parent::submitForm($form, $form_state); }
```

After saving admin form, **test_article_field** and **test_page_field**  is getting saved instead of selected field.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem in the submit handler.

Replace

```
$this->config('test.settings')
 ->set('test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field', $form_state->getValue('test', 'test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field'))
 ->save();
```

line with

```
$this->config('test.settings')
  ->set('test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field', $form_state->getValues('test_' . $content_type->get('type') . '_field'))
  ->save();
```

Hope that this helps you.

Comment: To explain a bit more in-depth for future readers, the issue is that getValue was called to find the `test` form key, which does not exist, so getValue takes the second argument as its default value. The code could also have been updated continue to use getValue if the form key was used as the first argument instead of the second argument.